# How to store common strings in a variable in mustache.js

Tags: javascript, variables, mustache

Is there a way in mustache to store common strings in the template? E.g., I have three inputs below but I don't want to enter `{ "ID":{{ID}},"table":"log_candidates" }` three times:

```
<input data-data='{ "ID":{{ID}},"table":"log_candidates" }' ...
<input data-data='{ "ID":{{ID}},"table":"log_candidates" }' ...
<input data-data='{ "ID":{{ID}},"table":"log_candidates" }' ...
```

In anycase I am putting all my templates in a php file so I can simple to this:

```
<?php $data = '{ "ID":{{ID}},"table":"log_candidates" }'; ?> 
<td><input data-data='<?= $data ?>' ..
```

Comment: Mustache is unclear on it, but if using [Nunjucks](http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks), which uses virtually the same syntax, that'd be simply `{% var varname = ... %}` and then you use that as `{{ varname }}` when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a partial.

```
<script type="text/html" id="myInput">
    <input data-data='{ "ID":{{ID}},"table":"log_candidates" }' ...
</script>  


{{> gimmeAnInput}}
{{> gimmeAnInput}} 
{{> gimmeAnInput}}

Mustache.render(template, view, {"gimmeAnInput": $("#myInput").html()});
```